# Typescript: define type with a getter and setter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a decorator that define property a class with a getter that return an `Observable` and setter that emit new value on subject.

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

export const defineDecorator = () => {
  return (target: object, propertyKey: string) => {
    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
      const sub = new Subject();
      const obs = sub.asObservable();
      get: (): any => {
        return obs;
      },
      set: (value: any) => {
        sub.next(value);
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    });
  }
};
```

I want specify in typescript, "value" propery is `Observable<string>` on "get" and `string` on "set":

```
export class MyComponent {
  @defineDecorator()
  value!: any; // instead of any.. what type?
}
```

what type for "value"?

Comment: Do you mean get(): Observable and set: (value: string) ?

Comment: @line88 yes! ...

Comment: I would think that this pattern is not idiomatic for RxJS code (perhaps even discourageable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is not currently supported in TypeScript (as of version `4.9.3` at least). Here's a simplified example which demonstrates the issue:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIDmEYyARnFMgBQCUAXDsgG5wA2ArhIwM5hShCyAL4BuZAHoAVPgJyAfotkAVABYooJDlBDIwATwAOKdDGRxkAcmJhL5hEh490VALYc+5FHCfBCIODI2FDAsYDAeKx4SO0RHZyoDY2oAJgBmAA4ABlpkKQlZaNIKKmpWTm5kPgEQQlpRXGFcIA)

```ts
interface Foo {
  get bar (): { value: string }; /*
      ~~~
  The return type of a 'get' accessor must be assignable to its 'set' accessor type(2380) */
  set bar (value: string);
}
```

Similar to the example above — in the code you've shown, the return type of the getter would be `Observable<string>`, which is not assignable to the setter's parameter type `string`.

---

You can read more context about this pattern and behavior at the following GitHub links:

- [microsoft/TypeScript #2521 - Suggestion: allow get/set accessors to be of different types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2521)
- [microsoft/TypeScript #43662 - Allow setter type to be incompatible with the getter type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43662)

Answer (score 1):

Per the previous answer, it's not possible but you can do it differently.
What if instead of plain property you return a function that will have overload signature and depending on how you can it will act as a setter or getter

```js
export const defineDecorator = () => (target: object, propertyKey: string) => {
  const sub = new Subject();
  const obs = sub.asObservable();

  Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value: (param: any) => {
      if (param !== undefined) {
        sub.next(param);
      } else {
        return obs;
      }
    },
  });
};

interface Value<T> {
  (): Observable<T>;
  (s: T): void;
}

export class MyComponent {
  @defineDecorator()
  value!: Value<string>;

  constructor() {
    // if used without param returns observable
    const shouldBeObservable = this.value();

    // if param is passed used as setter
    this.value('some string here');
  }
}
```